# condition expression in C

Tags: c, network-programming

```
#define sblock(sb, wf) ((sb)->sb_flags & SB_LOCK ? \
            (((wf) == M_WAITOK) ? sb_lock(sb) : EWOULDBLOCK) : \
            ((sb)->sb_flags |= SB_LOCK), 0)
```

I can't understand the last element "((sb)->sb_flags |= SB_LOCK), 0)". The "0" seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems, the idea here is to return `0` as the expression result once the side-effects of the statement `((sb)->sb_flags |= SB_LOCK)` were executed. The 
[C comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)
 is evaluating it's left side discarding the result, and returning the right side.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unnecessary, you have a ternary operator which requires two expressions.

It's made:

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

In your case you have

```
(sb->sb_flags & SB_LOCK) ? code : (sb->sb_flags != SB_LOCK, 0)
```

So `expression2` is `(sb->sb_flags != SB_LOCK, 0)` which means

- set bit `SB_LOCK` of `sb_flags`
- evaluate to `0`

(This because multiple expressions separated by a `,` evaluate as the value of the last expression)

Literally your code translates to

```
if (sb->sb_flags & SB_LOCK) {
  if (wf == M_WAITOK)
    return sb_lock(sb);
  else
    return EWOULDBLOCK;
}
else {
  sb->sb_flags |= SB_LOCK;
  return 0;
}
```